# Oracle Function Renaming while executing in Command prompt

Tags: oracle

Is there any SQL command that can rename a existing function or copy the same to another name.

Example : Function vishwa{} i will be changing it while executing on command prompt.
I need a backup of the same.

Answer (score 3):

There's no `ALTER FUNCTION ... RENAME` in Oracle

If you wish to backup the current version, run the

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION X ...
```

block replacing X by a backup function name

To retrieve the code for the Foo function:

```
select text from user_source s, user_objects o
where s.name = 'Foo' and s.name = o.object_name and o.object_type ='FUNCTION'
```

Comment: But how i know the contents of the Function that i have to back up i onloy know that name.?

Comment: @vishwa, Do you mean you don't have the source code? If so, you can retrieve it from the user_source view using the code in my answer.